# Android Jsoup spinner data retrieval

Tags: android, jsoup

https://namazvakitleri.diyanet.gov.tr/tr-TR

```
<div class="rs-dp-info hidden">Bölge Seçiniz :</div>
<form action="/tr-TR" method="post">                    <div class="rs-row">
                    <div class="rs-col-3">
                        <div class="rs-dp-holder">
                            <select class="country-select region-select" name="country" aria-label="Ülke Seçimi">
                                        <option value="33">ABD</option>
                                        <option value="166">AFGANISTAN</option>
                                        <option value="13">ALMANYA</option>
                                        <option value="17">ANDORRA</option>
                                        <option value="140">ANGOLA</option>
                                        <option value="125">ANGUILLA</option>
                                        <option value="90">ANTIGUA VE BARBUDA</option>
                                        <option value="199">ARJANTIN</option>
                                        <option value="25">ARNAVUTLUK</option>
                                        <option value="153">ARUBA</option>
                                        <option value="59">AVUSTRALYA</option>
                                        <option value="35">AVUSTURYA</option>
                                        <option value="5">AZERBAYCAN</option>
                                        <option value="54">BAHAMALAR</option>                                      
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The list of cities is complete. But I can't reach the cities of every city.

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private class Update extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String Url = "http://namazvakitleri.diyanet.gov.tr/tr-TR/";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(Url).get();

            Elements elements = doc.select("select[class=country-select region-select]").select("option");

            for (Element element : elements) {
                cityList.add(element.text());
                valueList.add(element.attr("value"));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

But I can't read the city. I can't sort this city. I have to read by choice.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, because, cities of the cities are not loaded on the page.
When you choose city, then it loads cities from that city.

You could it download manually

```
https://namazvakitleri.diyanet.gov.tr/tr-TR/home/GetRegList?ChangeType=state&CountryId=2&Culture=tr-TR&StateId=571
```

and change StateId to 572 etc....
But it would be time consuming and too many requestes.

Comment: yeah, it would better